# Create New Line after each Array Element

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to react and trying to teach it to myself. Trying to make an API call and loop through the records. I've been successful so far, however, I can't seem to figure out how to create a new line after each element that gets displayed. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just missing. Can someone advise here?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://api.randomuser.me/?results=10";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ person: data, loading: false, len: data.results.length });
    }

    render() {
      let items = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.len; i++) {
        const item = this.state.person.results[i].name.title;
        items.push(item);
      }
      
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
            <div>loading...</div>
          ) : (
            <div>
                {items}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` function to loop over the array display it in within the tags.

```
return (
        <div>
          {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
            <div>loading...</div>
          ) : (
            <div>
                {
                    items.map((item) => (
                        <>
                            <span>{item}</span>
                            <hr />
                        </>
                    )
                }
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
```

Comment: Perfect just what I needed. Thank you